# WebDriver test not running on IE11

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

When I run my WebDriver test they are not working at all.  What I've done so far:
1) I've updated my registry key to include FEATURE_BFCACHE
2) Protected mode settings are the same for all zones
3) Enhanced Protected Mode is disabled
4) I've also tried with setting IEDriverServer in my PATH

Test are working fine on Chrome, Firefox etc. but when I'm running on IE11 I get:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == a[href='#pricing'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 270 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'C025', ip: '169.254.167.218', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: 8bb9e652-976a-4b46-88dd-9fb339a0d352
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=11, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:23811/, handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

I'm using eclipse to write my code with java, the rest of my setup is:
1) selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
2) IEServerDriver.exe 32bit
3) Windows 7 64bit
4) java.version: 1.7.0_51

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have taken windows update **KB3025390** `IE` will not work as expected. There is currently no resolution to that yet. See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/TdY_rRNF-gw)

Also, Uninstalling the update KB3025390 should make the WebDriver work correctly with Internet Explorer 11. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839482/selenium-ie-webdriver-nosuchelementexception/27841139#comment44087009_27841139)

Comment: I searched all over for the solution but yours worked first time.  If I could vote up I would but thanks very much

Comment: Glad it helped. I know I hate `IE` :)

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way around the problem of an update installing automatically. You can just create a simple batch file with following content.

{code} @echo off

wusa /uninstall /kb:3025390/quiet /norestart

END {code}

Then go to task scheduler, create a new task for this batch file to run every one hour or day as per your requirements. Add it as a system task so it runs in the background and does not affect the running automations.

Comment: I like it. Way to beat `Microsoft` :P