# Selenium scripts fail after newest Windows update

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, updates

I have a question regarding Selenium and the current Microsoft updates:
I just installed the newest Microsoft patches on a PC and now the Selenium scripts won't work anymore. I'm using the `Selenium IE Driver 2.44.0` in the scripts. Maybe something has changed in the Internet Explorer, I'm not sure. Suddenly the scripts can't find any web elements on the page anymore. An `InvalidSelectorException` is thrown because the `findElements` methods can't be executed. The IE driver opens up and it navigates to the given URL, but when it tries to find a web element, the script fails. I also tried it out on a PC which hasn't the newest updates installed yet and the scripts are working fine there, there are no problems at all.
Do you have any ideas what to do or what could be the cause?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebDriver test not running on IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947515/webdriver-test-not-running-on-ie11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as I stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947515/webdriver-test-not-running-on-ie11/27947576#27947576)

If you have taken windows update **KB3025390** IE will not work as expected. There is currently no resolution to that yet.

Also, Uninstalling the update KB3025390 should make the WebDriver work correctly with Internet Explorer 11. See this answer

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! Now it's working fine again :)