# Selenium webdriver suddenly stopped working in IE

Tags: selenium, webdriver

My selenium webdriver tests were working fine in IE 11  and Firefox. But suddenly it stopped working in IE. Runs fine in Firefox and Chrome. 
I am using IE11, and did configured all the desired capabilities, also I did not modify any desired capabilities

```
InternetExplorerDriverService service = InternetExplorerDriverService.createDefaultService();
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "about:blank");
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false);
webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service, capabilities);
```

Can you suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as I stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069064/selenium-scripts-fail-after-newest-windows-update/28069601#28069601)

If you have taken windows update **KB3025390** IE will not work as expected.

Also, Uninstalling the update **KB3025390** should make the WebDriver work correctly with Internet Explorer 11. See this answer

Comment: Thank you, at least now I know the root cause. I have checked my security updates and I have KB3025390 , but uninstalling is not option for me as this is my office machine

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Upgrading the drivers and the IEServer to the most recent version fixed it.  It may not be your issue, but it worked for m.

Comment: I have the latest version of IEServerDriver and Selenium WebDriver, but it is still the same issue. Also, Uninstalling windows update KB3025390 is not an options as this is my office machine and Security updates cannot be uninstalled.  I found this                                                                               https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8302