# IEDriverServer on local HTML pages ends with NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11, python-3.4

I'm using 32-bit IE11 on Win8.1.
I have some Selenium scripts (Python bindings) which I execute on IE11 among others.

With IEDriverServer, I've done all the steps suggested on the [InternetExplorerDriver-wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) and in general the IEDriver works fine.

However, if I try to get a **local HTML page**, such as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
ie = webdriver.Ie()
url = "file:///D:/dev/proof_of_concept/html/liki.html"
ie.get(url)
print(ie.current_url)
```

I get this exception in return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 426, in current_url
return self.execute(Command.GET_CURRENT_URL)['value']
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: 'Unable to get browser'
```

There are many threads about the general IE11 issue (with the registry solution) but I weren't able to find any solution for this particular issue with **local pages**.

Is there some kind of limitation, or something related to the security zones, that I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196819/selenium-webdriver-suddenly-stopped-working-in-ie/28196882#28196882

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, the suggested resolution addresses a whole different issue, which I have already fixed earlier. Let me emphasize that so far I have managed to isolate the issue to local files. With normal web pages there are no problems.

Comment: I know that it's just a known issue I was pointing you to before banging your head against the wall because `IE` does not work. I do that all the time :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IE driver doesn't support opening HTML documents using the `file://` protocol. There are a number of reasons for this, but there are two in particular that feature prominently. First, JavaScript is disabled by default for documents opened in IE using the `file://` protocol. Since the IE driver requires JavaScript to function properly, this is a non-starter. Secondly, documents opened using the `file://` protocol are opened in a separate Protected Mode zone, one not normally displayed in the Options dialog. As such, it's not possible to avoid crossing a Protected Mode boundary, and when such a boundary is crossed, the COM objects the driver uses to automate IE get orphaned.

It's not difficult to launch a simple web server with which to serve up the documents you're interested in automating. That would be the correct way forward.

Comment: Thank you! I will proceed with a web server.