# Is there a native XPath support in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: selenium, xpath, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with my Selenium tests when using IEDriverServer.exe (32-bit). The same tests work fine in Firefox and Chrome browsers, but fail in Internet Explorer 11 with diagnostics:

> OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException : The xpath expression
>   '//input[@id='username']' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a
>   WebElement

It seems that IEDriver cannot find elements by XPath.
IEDriver version: 2.48.
Is there any workaround for this problem, except changing XPath with CSS locators?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible reason in comments for a similar problem:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839482/selenium-ie-webdriver-nosuchelementexception)
Update for IE11 KB3025390 (and latest ones) breaks IEDriver. When uninstall updates IEDriver successfully interacts with WebElements through XPath.